# where does the prime number taken in DH algorithm in IPSEC

Tags: diffie-hellman, prime-numbers, ipsec

I am studying & configuring IPSEC ikev1 and in between i am analysing the wireshark captures. I am using the linux kernel for TCP/IP stack and user-space i took ipsec-tools.

In the first two packet exchanges initiator is offering the proposals & responder will respond to the supported proposal.

Next two packet exchanges(packet 3[initiator] & 4[responder]) will perform DH key exchange.Here how the responder will came to know that which prime number the initiator uses & how it will be exchanged.

Answer (score 1):

It's in the SA payload of the initial packets.

It's attribute type 4 within the SA payload; in Main Mode of IKE (which is what you're looking at) the initiator will propose a list of groups, and the responder will pick one and send it back its selection in packet 2.

Now, what they exchange is a short integer value; both sides are expected to know the translation between the short values (current standard values are between 1 and 30) and the actual DH (or ECDH) group.  See [this page](http://www.iana.org/assignments/ipsec-registry/ipsec-registry.xhtml#ipsec-registry-10) for pointers to the definitions of the current standard groups.

Comment: Yeah i seen it in wireshark capture, In Transform IKE Attribute Type: Group Description 1024-bit MODP. There what it specifies? In this expression `A=g(pow)a mod p`. The g & p are generator and prime number respectively, how they choosen both same at initiator & responder.

Comment: @Kumar2080: if an IKE implementation supports group 2, it is expected to know that, for that group, $g=2$, and $p$ is the specific value listed in section 6.2 of RFC2409.